# How to attach diff Azure storage tables to save elmah logs

Tags: azure, elmah, azure-table-storage

I have installed elmah to my asp.net mvc application using below nuget package

```
<package id="Elmah.AzureTableStorage" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
```

Also i have configured Azure storage connection to store logs in to Azure tables as below

```
 <add name="ElmahAzureTableStorage" connectionString="{my connection string}" />
```

Now it's storing all error logs in Elmah table in Azure table storage , I would like to keep local & live error logs in different folder so is there any way i can define to use which table according to diff local & live env (web.config & web.release.config)?

Answer (score 1):

You should use web.config transformation for this, like described here: [Use multiple logs for different environments](https://docs.elmah.io/use-multiple-logs-for-different-environments/). The article uses [elmah.io](https://elmah.io/) as an example, but the approach is similar when using Azure table storage.

Basically, you need to configure the local environment in your `web.config` and "override" the `ElmahAzureTableStorage` setting in `web.release.config` like this:

```xml
<add
    key="ElmahAzureTableStorage"
    value="{my live connection string}"
    xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" 
    xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
```

Comment: I know that but actually I have same storage for local & release (dev) and different for production so I want to use diff tables for local & release

Comment: I don't believe you can do that, since the table name is hardcoded in Elmah.AzureTableStorage: https://github.com/MisinformedDNA/Elmah.AzureTableStorage/blob/master/src/Elmah.AzureTableStorage/AzureTableStorageErrorLog.cs#L17. Maybe send a pull request to the owner, making this possible: `<add name="ElmahAzureTableStorage:Table="mytable" .../>` or something similar.